# Navigator + hyperref

Tags: hyperref, packages, dependencies

Quick question: is the [`navigator` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/navigator) compatible with the [`hyperref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

It seems as though their responsibilities overlap somehow...

In which order should one load them?

Are there any other considerations for packages depending on one or the other (viz. the [`hypcap` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypcap))?

Comment: Usually you should load `hyperref` at the very last. However, `navigator` might have similar needs so you should put both at the very end. They don't seem incompatible per-se, a simple file compiles with both loaded. It is a pitty that the manual `navigator` (the newer package) doesn't mentions the compatibility with `hyperref` (the de-facto standard).

Comment: I suggest you ask this question in the `comp.text.tex` group, as the authors of both the `hyperref` and the `navigator` package are regular contributors to that forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @Mico I asked this very same question in the comp.text.tex group (thread [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/8b02cf0afaca4d4e)) and got the following answer from user zappathustra:

> No incompatibility. At worst they'll compete for the document's
>   properties (author, title, the way the PDF is displayed, etc.), but one
>   will win silently over the other. Anyway Navigator doesn't set those
>   properties automatically, but only if they're specified with the
>   "navigator" parameter.
>
> As for loading order, Navigator hasn't any requirement there, relative
>   to whatever other package.
>
> Best,
>   Paul

So I guess that settles it :)